# Crear un framework en Swift par Device/Ios Simulator

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode

Buenas tardes , he conseguido generar un pequeño framework ejemplo en swift pero solo me deja ejecutarlo si hago el deploy en un Device , he leído que si generas el framework con el simulador seleccionado podrías entonces ejecutar ese framework en un proyecto en el simulador , el problema es que si intento generar el framework para simulador me sigue saliendo el rojo el nombre.framework ...
También aprovecho para preguntar si no hay manera de generar un framework que me funcione tanto para Device como Simulador?
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si es posible generar el framework para ambas plataformas con `lipo` es lo que usaba antes para tener un framework "universal" el problema es que no puedes usarlo al distribuir la aplicación, lo que recomiendo es usar **Cocoapods** incluso si esta en una fase temprana de desarrollo el framework, puedes mantener todo local y facilita mucho las cosas; de cualquier para crear un framework para todas las plataformas puedes ejecutar este script [Universal Framework](https://gist.github.com/JuanjoArreola/ce6ae985098128758153610eba6565c1) cuando haces un *Archive* del framework

[image: Build settings]

El script va a crear una carpeta **Build** dentro de la carpeta de tu proyecto, pude que tengas que hacer build del proyecto con un simulador seleccionado antes de hacer *Archive*